# Not getting notification using AlaramManager in Android

Tags: android, android-alarms

MY code...

```
Button start = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button10);
    start.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Nortification_Reciver.class);
            PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(), 100, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
            AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
            Log.d("timeinmills", String.valueOf(calendar.getTimeInMillis()));
            alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, pendingIntent);


        }
    });
```

calender.getmills have correct values.

Nortification_Reciver.java

```
public class Nortification_Reciver extends BroadcastReceiver {
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    Intent i = new Intent(context, Add_data.class);
    i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 100, i, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
            .setContentTitle("Test")
            .setContentText("Text test")
            .setAutoCancel(true);

    notificationManager.notify(100, builder.build());
}
}
```

Manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="com.android.alarm.permission.SET_ALARM"/>

<receiver android:name=".Nortification_Reciver"/>
```

There is no notification showing. Whats wrong in this code.? How can i resolve this issue.? Is my service starting.?

Answer (score 0):

You are using AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, so add:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"/>
```

to your manifest. Btw, wrong classname Nortification :)

Comment: Your code seem right. Make sure your Calendar object is in the future or alarm will go off in tomorrow.